# how to add json data to the server and display it in the jqgrid right after a button clicked

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

i have a running program that will display my data from a server to the jqgrid. what i want now is to save data to the server. here's my code:

```
function Add(){
   var datas = {
   "ID": "xyz",
   "operation": "Add",
   "fields": ["code", "desc", "type"],
   "values": [$('#code').val(), $('#desc').val(), $('#type').val() ]
}

$('#tblData1').setGridParam({
    url:'myni.php?path=' + encodeURI('this/update') + '&json=' +(JSON.stringify(datas)), 
    datatype: Settings.ajaxDataType,  
});
    $('#tblData1').trigger('reloadGrid'); 
}
```

this codes returns an error message "Exception error: Server Error: Parameter 'operation' is not specified."  i already set an operation and i don't know what went wrong. can somebody help me fix this? please.

i want to know how to add data to the server after clicking the button and display it in the jqgrid right away. Please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `Add` set **local** variable `datas` which exist only inside of the `Add` function. Probably what you want is to return the value from the function and set to the variable existing in the scope of usage the `setGridParam` call.

The next problem is that you should encode `JSON.stringify(datas)` with respect of `encodeURIComponent`  before inserting it as the part of URL. You can also use [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) function instead:

```
url:'myni.php?' + $.param({path:'this/update', json:JSON.stringify(datas)})
```

If you use HTTP GET (`mtype:'GET'`) for requests to the server I would recommend you better to use `postData` parameter of jqGrid which contain functions:

```
$("list").jqGrid({
    url:'myni.php',
    postData: {
        path: 'this/update',
        json: function() {
            return JSON.stringify({
                ID: "xyz",
                operation: "Add",
                fields: ["code", "desc", "type"],
                values: [$('#code').val(), $('#desc').val(), $('#type').val()]
            });
        }
    },
    // other parameters
});
```

The properties of `postData` parameter will be added to the URL ('?' and '&' will be inserted if needed) in case of the usage of `mtype:'GET'` or to the body of the posted data in case of `mtype:'POST'`.

The advantage of the usage functions inside of `postData` is that the corresponding values (like the value of `json` parameter) **will be calculated on every ajax request**. If the user changes the sort order or chooses another page the ajax request to the server will be send. So in the case the `postData` properties must be determined and **the current** values from `$('#code').val()`, `$('#desc').val()` and `$('#type').val()` will be inserted in the request.

If the value of `path` parameter should not be static you can make it also as the function.

In case of usage `postData` which includes functions you code could be reduced to `$('#tblData1').setGridParam({datatype: Settings.ajaxDataType}).trigger('reloadGrid')`.

More about the usage of functions inside of `postData` you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819).

Comment: Oleg, this is now my code. it returns an error 'parsererror'.               var datas = {
    ...
  };
  
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '...php?' + $.param({path:'.../update', json:JSON.stringify(datas)}),
   
    dataType: Settings.ajaxDataType,
    data: 'json=' + JSON.stringify(datas),
    success: function(data) {
      if ('error' in data)
      {
        ...
      }
      alert(JSON.stringify(datas));
    }
  });

  $('#tblData1').setGridParam({datatype: primeSettings.ajaxDataType}).trigger('reloadGrid');

Comment: You should remove `data: 'json=' + JSON.stringify(datas)` part if you use `$.param` in the url. In the case the best seems me `$.ajax({ type: 'GET', url:'...php',data: {path:'.../update', json:JSON.stringify(datas)}, success: ... });` In the case the value from the `data` parameter will be processed by `$.param` and appended to the url **by $.ajax** itself.

Comment: i now already edit the code but it didn't add. and if i put this code "$('#tblData1').setGridParam({datatype: primeSettings.ajaxDataType}).trigger('reloadGrid');",  the "parsererror" shows... what went wrong?

Comment: Could you post full code example which can be used to reproduce your problem (including the test JSON data for `datas`)?

Comment: hey Oleg, its working now. i was so lame, its the "Add" word to "add". thank you so much. you help me again.